# Title: Issue with Date Formatting in dxi-column Using DevExtreme in Angular

Tags: html, angular, format, devexpress, devextreme

I am encountering an issue with formatting dates in the dxi-column component using the DevExtreme library in an Angular project. Below is the snippet of code that doesn't seem to be working as expected:

```
<dxi-column dataField="DtCrt"
           caption="Utworzenie wymagania"
           [allowEditing]="false"
           [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'"></dxi-column>
```

I expected the date to be displayed in the 'MM/dd/yyyy' format, but it continues to appear in the default format. I have tried various formatting methods, but none have worked.
Could anyone help me understand what I might be doing wrong or suggest what I could do differently to achieve the desired date format? Is there a specific way of formatting dates in DevExtreme that I should be aware of?
Any suggestions or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use Date Formatting format in dxi-column DevExtreme, you can do like this and this works!

```html
<dxi-column
  dataField="DtCrt"
  caption="Utworzenie wymagania"
  [allowEditing]="false">
  <dxo-format
     skeleton="yMd">
  </dxo-format>
</dxi-column>
```

you can see more information
https://js.devexpress.com/Angular/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Object_Structures/format/

Comment: sry bro but it dont work in my project